# How to properly work with promises, Firebase and React's UseEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to run some code only after a variable is not undefined anymore. However, I'm feeling very confused with the use of promises to await firebase responses, as well as with the use of React's useEffect hook.

I did some research that perhaps listeners are my answer to this? I couldn't really figure out how to implement them, though.

```
const weekday = moment().isoWeekday() 

export const TimeGrid = () => {
  const { userObject } = useContext(Context)

  //(1) I wish to use the below to generate a list of times
  const [LIST_OF_TIMES_FROM_DATABASE, SET_LIST_OF_TIMES_FROM_DATABASE] = useState([])

  let businessId

  function getBusinessId() {
    if (userObject) businessId = userObject.businessId
  }

  getBusinessId()

  //defines function that will run below inside of first useEffect
  //also where the list of times is supposed to be set
  function getWorkingHoursAccordingToDayOfTheWeek(day, snapshot) {
    const workingHours = []
    const ALL_AVAILABLE_TIMES = []

    workingHours.push(snapshot.data().beginWeek)
    workingHours.push(snapshot.data().endWeek)

    const [begin, ending] = workingHours
    let bgn = moment(begin, 'HH:mm')
    const end = moment(ending, 'HH:mm')
    let i = 0
    while (bgn <= end) {
      ALL_AVAILABLE_TIMES.push({
        id: i,
        type: 'time',
        day: 'today',
        time: bgn.format('HHmm'),
      })
      bgn = bgn.add(30, 'minutes')
      i++
    }
    SET_LIST_OF_TIMES_FROM_DATABASE(ALL_AVAILABLE_TIMES) //(2) This is where I set the list, which won't work on its 1st run
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getTimesFromDB() {
      const approved = await approvedBusinessService.doc(businessId)
      const snapshotApproved = await approved.get()
      if (snapshotApproved.exists) {
        getWorkingHoursAccordingToDayOfTheWeek(weekday, snapshotApproved)
        return
      } else {
        const pending = await businessPendingApprovalService.doc(businessId)
        const snapshotPending = await pending.get()
        if (snapshotPending.exists) {
          getWorkingHoursAccordingToDayOfTheWeek(weekday, snapshotPending)
        }
      }
      return
    }

    getTimesFromDB()
  }, [userObject])

  const allBookedTimes = allBookings.map(element => element.time)
  //the below used to be 'listOfTimesJSON.map(item => item.time)' and used to work as it was a static JSON file
  //(3) this is sometimes undefined... so all of the code below which relies on this will not run
  const listOfTimes = LIST_OF_TIMES_FROM_DATABASE.map(item => item.time)

  const [counts, setCounts] = useState({})
  useEffect(() => {
    const counts = {}
    //(4) below will not work as listOfTimes won't exist (because of 'LIST_OF_TIMES_FROM_DATABASE' being undefined)
    listOfTimes.forEach(x => {
      counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1 

      if (allBookedTimes.includes(x)) counts[x] = counts[x] - 1
    })
    setCounts(counts)
  }, [])

  const sortedListOfTimesAndCount = Object.keys(counts).sort() //(5) undefined, because 'counts' was undefined.
  const displayListOfTimes = sortedListOfTimesAndCount.map(
    time =>
      time > currentTime && (
        <>
          <li>
            {time}
          </li>
        </>
      ),
  )

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>{displayListOfTimes}</ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as per the comments in your code your steps 3 ,4 ,5 are dependent on `LIST_OF_TIMES_FROM_DATABASE`
and it's also not in sequence,

And you are expecting it to execute in the sequence,

1) First, it will execute all the thing which is outside the `useEffect` and it's dependency whenever there is change in `state`, so keep that in mind

2) `useEffect(() => {...},[])` this will get called as soon as component mounts, so in most cases, you will get `listOfTimes` as `[]`, because at that time API call might be in requesting data from server.

3) There are few unnecessary things like `const [counts, setCounts] = useState({})` and `useEffect(() => {...} , [])`, this is kind of overuse of functionality.

Sometimes you can do the things simply but with all these it becomes complicated

---

**Solution :**

So what you can do is just put all the code inside `displayListOfTimes` function and check for `LIST_OF_TIMES_FROM_DATABASE` if available then and only then proceed with steps 3,4,5. So you will never get `LIST_OF_TIMES_FROM_DATABASE` undefined

> NOTE : And as per the code `LIST_OF_TIMES_FROM_DATABASE` either be blank
>   `array` or array with `data` but never `undefined`, and if you are getting undefined then you can check that while setting up the state

```
const weekday = moment().isoWeekday() 

export const TimeGrid = () => {
  const { userObject } = useContext(Context)

  //(1) I wish to use the below to generate a list of times
  const [LIST_OF_TIMES_FROM_DATABASE, SET_LIST_OF_TIMES_FROM_DATABASE] = useState([])

  let businessId

  function getBusinessId() {
    if (userObject) businessId = userObject.businessId
  }

  getBusinessId()

  //defines function that will run below inside of first useEffect
  //also where the list of times is supposed to be set
  function getWorkingHoursAccordingToDayOfTheWeek(day, snapshot) {
    const workingHours = []
    const ALL_AVAILABLE_TIMES = []

    workingHours.push(snapshot.data().beginWeek)
    workingHours.push(snapshot.data().endWeek)

    const [begin, ending] = workingHours
    let bgn = moment(begin, 'HH:mm')
    const end = moment(ending, 'HH:mm')
    let i = 0
    while (bgn <= end) {
      ALL_AVAILABLE_TIMES.push({
        id: i,
        type: 'time',
        day: 'today',
        time: bgn.format('HHmm'),
      })
      bgn = bgn.add(30, 'minutes')
      i++
    }
    SET_LIST_OF_TIMES_FROM_DATABASE(ALL_AVAILABLE_TIMES) //(2) This is where I set the list, which won't work on its 1st run
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getTimesFromDB() {
      const approved = await approvedBusinessService.doc(businessId)
      const snapshotApproved = await approved.get()
      if (snapshotApproved.exists) {
        getWorkingHoursAccordingToDayOfTheWeek(weekday, snapshotApproved)
        return
      } else {
        const pending = await businessPendingApprovalService.doc(businessId)
        const snapshotPending = await pending.get()
        if (snapshotPending.exists) {
          getWorkingHoursAccordingToDayOfTheWeek(weekday, snapshotPending)
        }
      }
      return
    }

    getTimesFromDB()
  }, [userObject])


  const displayListOfTimes = () => { // <----- Start - HERE
    if(LIST_OF_TIMES_FROM_DATABASE && LIST_OF_TIMES_FROM_DATABASE.length) {
      const counts = {}
      const allBookedTimes = allBookings.map(element => element.time)

      //(3) ------ this will never be undefined
      const listOfTimes = LIST_OF_TIMES_FROM_DATABASE.map(item => item.time)

      //(4) ------ now it will work always
      listOfTimes.forEach(x => {
        counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1 

        if (allBookedTimes.includes(x)) counts[x] = counts[x] - 1
      })

      //(5) ------ now it will work 
      const sortedListOfTimesAndCount = Object.keys(counts).sort() 
      return sortedListOfTimesAndCount.map(
        time =>
          time > currentTime && (
            <>
              <li>
                {time}
              </li>
            </>
          ),
      )
    } else {
      return <li>Nothing to show for now</li>
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>{displayListOfTimes}</ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it won't work. the ```displayListOfTimes``` won't run. I then tried calling the function with ```displayListOfTimes()``` which will run but the setState call will do too many rerenders. I've also tried ```() => displayListOfTimes()``` but that won't run either. What am I doing wrong? Here's what I tried to do https://github.com/user0x1d/firestore-promises-useeffect/blob/master/TimeGrid.js

Comment: There is some limitation with useEffect Async call, you may need to consider the useAsyncEffect, have a look here https://greatrexpectations.com/2019/07/11/async-effects-with-hooks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you useEffect which uses `listOfTimes` isn't being called when the listOfTimes value updates after a fetch request.

You can define `listOfTimes` within the useEffect and add a dependency on `LIST_OF_TIMES_FROM_DATABASE`

```
  const [counts, setCounts] = useState({})
  useEffect(() => {
    // Defining it inside because if we don't and add allBookedTimes as a dependency then it will lead to an infinite look since references will change on each re-render

    const allBookedTimes = allBookings.map(element => element.time)
    const listOfTimes = LIST_OF_TIMES_FROM_DATABASE.map(item => item.time)
    const counts = {}
    listOfTimes.forEach(x => {
      counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1 

      if (allBookedTimes.includes(x)) counts[x] = counts[x] - 1
    })
    setCounts(counts)
  }, [LIST_OF_TIMES_FROM_DATABASE, allBookings]); // Add both dependencies. This will ensure that you update counts state when the state for times changes
```